# CSS White Space At Bottom of Page

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

How can I get rid of the space at the bottom of the page?

```css
/* Basic Style */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
a:link {
  color: #42b4da;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #002946;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #670f08;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
img {
  border: 0px solid white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/* Text Formatting */

h1 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
blockquote {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/* Clear */

.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
}
/* Page Wrapper*/

#pageWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Page Top */

#pageTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#topTitle {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#topRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
/* Page Main */

#pageMain {
  background: #ffffff url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Main Content */

#mainContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
.contentClear {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
.contentPost {
  margin: 40px;
}
.postTitle {} .postContent {} .postExtras {}
/* Main Sidebar */

#mainSidebar {
  background: #262626 url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
#mainSidebar h1 {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font: 14pt'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:before {
  content: "â€¹";
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:after {
  content: "â€º";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
.sidebarContent {} .sidebarNav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebarNav li:before {
  content: "//";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
/* Page Footer */

#pageFooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footerContent {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#footerRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageWrapper">
  <div id="pageTop">
    <div id="topTitle">
      This is where the pages logo/title/whatever will go.
    </div>
    <div id="topRight">
      Rightside content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
  <div id="pageMain">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div class="contentClear">
        <div class="contentPost">
          <div class="postTitle">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="postExtras">
            <p>
              APRIL 2, 2015 1 COMMENT
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="postContent">
            <p>
              Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
            </p>
            <p>
              This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts
              content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainSidebar">
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Navigation</h1>
        <ul class="sidebarNav">
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Links</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Unordered List</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Something Else</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
  <div id="pageFooter">
    <div id="footerContent">
      <h1>This is the footer, and copyright stuff.</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Links</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footerRight">
      <p>
        SMLinks
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried `html, body {
 height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}` ?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are asking for. Could you simplify your example code and more clearly communicate what you are having trouble with? "This space at the bottom" isn't very descriptive. What space? Do you mean the space between the footer and the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: Tried editing OPs post to share this image but I can't due to "too much code error".
Here is what his problem looks like:
http://i.imgur.com/YuF3BWc.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the problem is that there's a persistent vertical scroll bar even when there is no content to fill that scroll area.

I believe this is caused by ["margin collapse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

### Explaination of the Margin Collapse

You've set `div#pageTop` to `position:fixed` and you've added `margin-top:100px` to `div#pageMain` to push it down below the fixed header. That margin collapses with `div#pageWrapper` and ultimately with the `<body>`.

Since the `<body>` is set to `height:100%` and the collapsing margin pushes it down 100px, the `<body>` ends up being 100px too tall and causes a vertical scrollbar in the browser. A height of `100% + 100px` will *always* be greater than the window's height and will always require a scroll bar.

Below is an image showing the top of `<body>`. Note that it does not start at the top of the page as expected. It starts 100px down, below the header:

[image]

### How to Fix the Collapsing Margin

There are [several methods](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/) to prevent collapsing margins. In this context, I suggest changing the `margin-top:100px` on `div#pageMain` into padding:

```css
#pageMain {
  ...
  padding-top: 100px; /* padding instead of margin */
}
```

This stops the margin from collapsing and brings the `<body>` back up to the top of the window where it belongs:

[image]

Now the height of the `<body>` is 100% of the window and there is no persistent scroll bar.

See the demonstration below:

```css
/* Basic Style */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
a:link {
  color: #42b4da;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #002946;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #670f08;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
img {
  border: 0px solid white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/* Text Formatting */

h1 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
blockquote {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/* Clear */

.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
}
/* Page Wrapper*/

#pageWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Page Top */

#pageTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#topTitle {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#topRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
/* Page Main */

#pageMain {
  background: #ffffff url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Main Content */

#mainContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
.contentClear {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
.contentPost {
  margin: 40px;
}
.postTitle {} .postContent {} .postExtras {}
/* Main Sidebar */

#mainSidebar {
  background: #262626 url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
#mainSidebar h1 {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font: 14pt'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:before {
  content: "â€¹";
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:after {
  content: "â€º";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
.sidebarContent {} .sidebarNav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebarNav li:before {
  content: "//";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
/* Page Footer */

#pageFooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footerContent {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#footerRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageWrapper">
  <div id="pageTop">
    <div id="topTitle">
      This is where the pages logo/title/whatever will go.
    </div>
    <div id="topRight">
      Rightside content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
  <div id="pageMain">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div class="contentClear">
        <div class="contentPost">
          <div class="postTitle">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="postExtras">
            <p>
              APRIL 2, 2015 1 COMMENT
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="postContent">
            <p>
              Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
            </p>
            <p>
              This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts
              content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainSidebar">
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Navigation</h1>
        <ul class="sidebarNav">
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Links</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Unordered List</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Something Else</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
  <div id="pageFooter">
    <div id="footerContent">
      <h1>This is the footer, and copyright stuff.</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Links</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footerRight">
      <p>
        SMLinks
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The answer by jlane09 also solves this issue. It has validity because it works. However, in my opinion, that answer does not adequately explain the *cause* of the problem. Also, using `height:auto` could cause further problems in some contexts (e.g. using percentage-based heights for child elements).

---

### Sticky Footer

Creating a "sticky" footer is a separate issue. If you want the footer to always stick to the bottom of the window regardless of whether the window needs to scroll, see [Ryan Fait's (famous) sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). It requires somewhat of a different structure, but it's worth it.

I built you a rudimentary demo, below:

```css
/* Basic Style */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Page Wrapper*/

#pageWrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 -160px;
}
/* Page Top */

#pageTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
#topTitle {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#topRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
/* Page Main */

#pageMain {
  background: #ffffff url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
/* Main Content */

#mainContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
.contentClear {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
.contentPost {
  margin: 40px;
}
.postTitle {} .postContent {} .postExtras {}
/* Main Sidebar */

#mainSidebar {
  background: #262626 url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
#mainSidebar h1 {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font: 14pt'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:before {
  content: "â€¹";
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:after {
  content: "â€º";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
.sidebarContent {} .sidebarNav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebarNav li:before {
  content: "//";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
/* Page Footer */

#pageFooter {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
}
#footerContent {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#footerRight {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
#pageFooter,
#footer_push {
  height: 160px;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
  /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

```html
<div id="pageWrapper">
  <div id="pageTop">
    <div id="topTitle">This is where the pages logo/title/whatever will go.</div>
    <div id="topRight">Rightside content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pageMain" class="clearfix">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div class="contentClear">
        <div class="contentPost">
          <div class="postTitle">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>

          </div>
          <div class="postExtras">
            <p>APRIL 2, 2015 1 COMMENT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="postContent">
            <p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>
            <p>This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This
              is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainSidebar">
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Navigation</h1>

        <ul class="sidebarNav">
          <li> <a href="_blank">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="_blank">About</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="_blank">Contact</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="_blank">Links</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Unordered List</h1>

        <ul>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Something Else</h1>

        <ol>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
          <li>Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer_push"></div>
</div>
<div id="pageFooter">
  <div id="footerContent">
    <h1>This is the footer, and copyright stuff.</h1>

    <ul>
      <li> <a href="_blank">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="_blank">About</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="_blank">Contact</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="_blank">Links</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footerRight">
    <p>SMLinks</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for better explaining it, I made the change you suggested as well!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have height: 100%; on your html and body tags. Also, it is on your pageWrapper class. This tells the browser to make the height of the page at least the height of the viewport no matter what, and then tells your inner pageWrapper class to match that height, no matter what.

I would suggest making html height: auto; for a start.

Comment: How does what you describe create white space at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Because your pageWrapper class has the height of the viewport, which is greater than the height of all the content on the page. So, if there isnt enough content to fill the page you will see whitespace

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was referring to the extra space he was getting, it was causing a scroll bar to appear.

Comment: This worked perfectly; I will admit the css thats at the start is copied from a site I made quite some time ago. I was being a bit lazy, and by god I really need to read up on modern CSS XD

Answer (score 1):

The div class "question" is 2032 pixels tall.  Underneath this div is one called "answer" that is a blank div that is 728 X 870px.  The white space can be eliminated by shrinking the answer div to eliminate some of the white space.  However some white space is because of the answer area.  To learn how to change the CSS visit http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp. The code to find these divs are under body, container, content, itemscope, and then mainbar.

Comment: The `<div>` elements you describe are part of the structure of StackOverflow and not part of the OP's code.

Comment: Yes that is why there is space at the bottom of the page.  I took his code and copied that into a HTML document.  After opening it in Google Chrome, there is no white space in the bottom of it.  The navigation bar was at the bottom of the page like it was intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you intended the black background footer section to reside at the bottom with no white space beneath, right?  You can do that by taking the footer section out of the page wrapper, put it right before the end body tag and add this css:

For ID pageFooter add css position:fixed; bottom:0;

```css
/* Basic Style */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
a:link {
  color: #42b4da;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #002946;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #670f08;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
img {
  border: 0px solid white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/* Text Formatting */

h1 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
blockquote {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/* Clear */

.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
}
/* Page Wrapper*/

#pageWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Page Top */

#pageTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#topTitle {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#topRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
/* Page Main */

#pageMain {
  background: #ffffff url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Main Content */

#mainContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
.contentClear {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
.contentPost {
  margin: 40px;
}
.postTitle {} .postContent {} .postExtras {}
/* Main Sidebar */

#mainSidebar {
  background: #262626 url(../style/images/sidebarBackground.gif) repeat-y right;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
#mainSidebar h1 {
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font: 14pt'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:before {
  content: "â€¹";
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}
#mainSidebar h1:after {
  content: "â€º";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
.sidebarContent {} .sidebarNav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebarNav li:before {
  content: "//";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}
/* Page Footer */

#pageFooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footerContent {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
#footerRight {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#footerContent h1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
}
#footerContent ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#footerContent ul li {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/*  ADD THIS TO FIX FOOTER TO BOTTOM  */
#pageFooter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageWrapper">
  <div id="pageTop">
    <div id="topTitle">
      This is where the pages logo/title/whatever will go.
    </div>
    <div id="topRight">
      Rightside content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
  <div id="pageMain">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div class="contentClear">
        <div class="contentPost">
          <div class="postTitle">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="postExtras">
            <p>
              APRIL 2, 2015 1 COMMENT
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="postContent">
            <p>
              Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
            </p>
            <p>
              This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts
              content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!! This is the posts content; yeah!!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainSidebar">
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Navigation</h1>
        <ul class="sidebarNav">
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="_blank">Links</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Unordered List</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebarContent">
        <h1>Something Else</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
          <li>
            Here is an unordered list in the sidebar.
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
  <div id="pageFooter">
    <div id="footerContent">
      <h1>FIXED FOOTER &copy;2015 etc.</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="_blank">Links</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footerRight">
      <p>
        SMLinks
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use code snippets unless you've got something that actually "runs".

Comment: The code snippet was really simple and something that 'actually works', so I thought it might be helpful.  I've gone ahead and added the entire original code with the fixed footer css, all righty then.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing `line-height:100%` from your `body`.
Add `height:100vh` to you `#mainPage`.

```
#mainPage{
height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can help to clarify the question. What exactly did you fix? What problem are you addressing?

Comment: In the OP's post/code, his footer is floating about 1/3 up from the bottom of the page. He has the `line-height:100%` which is pushing it up from the bottom, and adding the `height:100vh` makes his `#mainPage` the same height as the browser window.

Comment: Strange, I don't see the footer floating at all. It butts right up against the bottom of the snippet window. Do you mean in the "full screen" version, the space below all the content?

Comment: @showdev I'm on a 2014 15" MacBook Pro with the full page open, running google chrome
http://i.imgur.com/YuF3BWc.png